# MongoDB mapReduce array key values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

i'm fullstack web developer. I'm using asyncawait and mapReduce and i want sum all client events by conditions in DB.
My code:

```
var mapReduceLoyalty = async(function (clients, dtTill, eventTypes, periodLoyalty) {

// Init mapReduce object
  var mapReduce = {};

  mapReduce.scope = {
    // this array of ObjectIds of clients
    clients: clients,
    // this array of ObjectIds of eventTypes (4 elements)
    eventTypes: eventTypes
  };

  mapReduce.jsMode = true;

  // i want sum count of events by condition of each client in array
  mapReduce.map = function () {
    for (var i = 0, len = clients.length; i < len; i++) {
      var key = clients[i];

      var value = {
        count: (eventTypes.indexOf(this._eventType)) ? 1 : 0
      };
      emit(key, value);
    }
  };

  mapReduce.reduce = function (key, values) {
    var reduceObject = {};
    reduceObject.client = key;
    reduceObject.count = 0;

    values.forEach(function (value) {
      reduceObject.count += value
    });

    return reduceObject;
  };

  mapReduce.query = {};
  mapReduce.keeptemp = false;

  // where dtEnd less then dtTill date
  mapReduce.query['dtEnd'] = {
    "$lt": dtTill
  };

  var result = await(Event.mapReduce(mapReduce).exec());
  return result;
```

This code doing nothing . Only stops at the line

```
var result = await(Event.mapReduce(mapReduce).exec());
```

I'm newbie in map Reduce. What i'm doing wrong ? May be asyncawait ?

Comment: Can you show us what you are trying to achieve here? Some sample documents and the expected output would be great here. I believe there's a much better approach to solve your issue, using aggregation framework.

Comment: Yes, in the begin i'm using Aggregation Framework, but then tell me how and where using mapReduce ? i think this case better compute with mapReduce..